# Animate multiple UIViews alpha

Tags: ios, swift

I have multiple labels placed on scroll view  like:

```
private func drawDates(_ multiplier: Double){
        contentView.subviews.forEach{it in
            it.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let maximumVisibleDates = 6.0
        let dateLabelOffset = Double(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(maximumVisibleDates))
        let doublePoints = data.findClosestDatePointsForInterval(interval: dateLabelOffset,
                                                                 multiplier: multiplier)
        print(doublePoints)
        let datesToShow = data.datesForPoints(points: doublePoints, multiplier: multiplier)

        for (index, value) in datesToShow.enumerated(){
            if index == datesToShow.count - 1 {
               continue
            }

            let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: CGFloat(doublePoints[index]),
                                                        y: Dimensions.chartHeight.value + Offsets.small.value,
                                                        width: Dimensions.dateLabelWidth.value,
                                                        height: Dimensions.dateLabelHeight.value))
            label.text = redableString(value)
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: FontSizes.yLabel.value)
            label.textColor = Settings.isLightTheme() ? Colors.LightTheme.textGray.value : Colors.DarkTheme.textGray.value
            label.sizeToFit()
            contentView.addSubview(label)
        }
    }
```

When i call:

```
contentView.subviews.forEach{it in
                it.removeFromSuperview()
            }
```

Actually i want to fade "old" labels from old function call and then add new labels animated. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to remove old view and add new view with animation.

**Solution 1:**

1. Set new view alpha to 0 and add it to super view.
2. Do animation.
3. Remove old view after animation.

In this case, use for loop in `animations` block to set alpha, and in `completion` block to remove old views.

```
let viewToAdd = ...
viewToAdd.alpha = 0
contentView.addSubview(viewToAdd)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    viewToRemove.alpha = 0
    viewToAdd.alpha = 1
}, completion: { (_) in
    viewToRemove.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

**Solution 2:**

Call `transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)` method. Use `.transitionCrossDissolve` as `options` value.

In this case, use for loop in `animations` block to remove old views and add new views.

```
UIView.transition(with: contentView,
                  duration: 1,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve, 
                  animations: {
                    viewToRemove.removeFromSuperview()
                    contentView.addSubview(viewToAdd)
}, completion: nil)
```

**Solution 3:**

If the number of old views is equal to the number of new views, call `transition(from:to:duration:options:completion:)` method. Use `.transitionCrossDissolve` as `options` value.

In this case, use for loop to call the method.

```
UIView.transition(from: viewToRemove,
                  to: viewToAdd,
                  duration: 1,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                  completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the `UIView` animation API:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration

Comment: Example would be great